# implementing a database browser elm-lang

Tags: spring-mvc, elm

I am learning to use elm for building UI.
I need to add some new functionality in our existing application which uses extjs and spring mvc. 
First of all, is it a relatively easy task to add elm based UI into the extjs based UI ? 
Is it possible to use spring mvc as the backend ?
are there any sample applications that use spring mvc and elm. I have not found any.
Any tips on how to go about introducing elm to an existing extjs and spring mvc application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all, is it a relatively easy task to add elm based UI into the extjs based UI ?

It should be easy. Elm can be embedded within a div. Please take a look at the [interop guide](http://elm-lang.org/guide/interop#html-embedding).

> Is it possible to use spring mvc as the backend ?

The easiest way would be to implement a JSON REST-full API with spring and consume that API with an Elm App. [Elm Architecture Tutorial](https://github.com/evancz/elm-architecture-tutorial) example 5 shows how to consume a JSON API. (It uses an API that provides a random cat GIF)

> Any tips on how to go about introducing elm to an existing extjs and spring mvc application.

Isolate a section that would become the responsibility of the Elm sub-app. Implement all the views and the actions of that section in Elm using the Elm Architecture Tutorial.